# AWS Lambda creating DynamoDB Table and enabling a Stream and attaching a Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am writing a lambda function which is the recipient of a DynamoDB stream. This invoked lambda should be creating a dynamodb table and enable streaming and attach a lambda trigger. Here is my code -

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    for (const record of event.Records) {
        let tableStreamArn = '';

        if(record.eventName == 'REMOVE') {
            return null;
        }

        if(record.eventName == 'INSERT') {
            console.log("Campaign Id here : ", record.dynamodb.NewImage.campaignId.N);
            const campaignId = record.dynamodb.NewImage.campaignId.N;

            const params = {
                AttributeDefinitions: [
                    {
                        AttributeName: "userId",
                        AttributeType: "S"
                    },
                    {
                        AttributeName: "externalDateTime",
                        AttributeType: "S"
                    }
                ],
                KeySchema: [
                    {
                        AttributeName: "userId",
                        KeyType: "HASH"
                    },
                    {
                        AttributeName: "externalDateTime",
                        KeyType: "RANGE"
                    }
                ],
                BillingMode: 'PAY_PER_REQUEST',
                TableName: `CampaignId-${campaignId}-RawVotes`,
                StreamSpecification: {
                    StreamEnabled: true,
                    StreamViewType: 'NEW_IMAGE'
                }
            };

            await dynamodb.createTable(params).promise().then(async data => {
                console.log("Successfully created Table", data);

                tableStreamArn = data.TableDescription.LatestStreamArn;

                console.log("Table stream ARN here : ", tableStreamArn);

                let esmParams = {
                    FunctionName: process.env.AGGREGATION_FUNCTION_NAME,
                    Enabled: true,
                    EventSourceArn: tableStreamArn,
                    StartingPosition: 'LATEST',
                };

               await lambda.createEventSourceMapping(esmParams).promise().then(data => {
                    console.log("Successfully attached event : ", data);
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("Error creating event source mapping : ", err);
                });
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("Error table creation here : ", err);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

The `lambda.createEventSourceMapping` never gets called unfortunately. If i keep it in a simple lambda function and not in the records loop, it works fine. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely because your table is not in an active state when you try to attach the mapping.

Check your CloudTrail logs for CreateEventSourceMapping to see the exception.

Try adding a delay after table creation before adding the mapping, or better call DescribeTable and ensure status=Active before creating the mapping.

Comment: I tried to add dynamodb.waitFor to wait for the table exist state but it somehow goes into an infinite loop of creating the table and then errors out since the table is existing -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#waitFor-property

Comment: To understand if this is your issue, simply add a timeout of 1min to your code. Then see if the EventSourceMapping is created.

Comment: TableStreamArn is printed and then i have a timeout for 1 min. It waits but and then finishes execution. But the trigger is not added. And the lambda goes into another execution and errors out since the table is already created

Comment: Do you have exceptions in your Cloudtrail logs?

Comment: Cant find anything if i filter with Event name and look for CreateEventSourceMapping. I get some logs from yesterday. Can this be a problem with my lambda inside the VPC? But, I also have a DDB gateway endpoint in place

Comment: Worked out, had a permission issue in the destination lambda. Strange that when it is inside a VPC no error shows up

Comment: but works without the lambdas in VPC, within a VPC it stops working again. seems like a accessing the DDB stream from within a VPC is getting blocked

Comment: If you want access to a stream from within a vpc your lambda needs to have internet access via a NAT or IGW.

Comment: i have IGW actually attached to the subnets